# Click detection in a 2D isometric grid?

Tags: javascript, click, 2d, detection, isometric

I've been doing web development for years now and I'm slowly getting myself involved with game development and for my current project I've got this isometric map, where I need to use an algorithm to detect which field is being clicked on. This is all in the browser with Javascript by the way.

**The map**
It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4cPq.jpg) and I've added some numbers to show you the structure of the fields (tiles) and their IDs. All the fields have a center point (array of x,y) which the four corners are based on when drawn.
As you can see it's not a diamond shape, but a zig-zag map and there's no angle (top-down view) which is why I can't find an answer myself considering that all articles and calculations are usually based on a diamond shape with an angle.

**The numbers**
It's a dynamic map and all sizes and numbers can be changed to generate a new map.
I know it isn't a lot of data, but the map is generated based on the map and field sizes.
- Map Size: x:800 y:400
- Field Size: 80x80 (between corners)
- Center position of all the fields (x,y)

**The goal**
To come up with an algorithm which tells the client (game) which field the mouse is located in at any given event (click, movement etc).

**Disclaimer**
I do want to mention that I've already come up with a working solution myself, however I'm 100% certain it could be written in a better way (my solution involves a lot of nested if-statements and loops), and that's why I'm asking here.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8zRj.jpg) an example of my solution where I basically find a square with corners in the nearest 4 known positions and then I get my result based on the smallest square between the 2 nearest fields. Does that make any sense?

Ask if I missed something.

Comment: Wait a minute... Are you saying that the corners of the graph in the image are not adjacent to each other?

Comment: @albert if you mean whether all the cells are touching each other then yes, they are but if you're asking whether there's more outside the map then no. The images I've posted display the exact map size without any kind of scrolling or so.

Comment: Well, it's a subset of a diamond shaped map. Can you use a sparse array and just cut out the corners, or whatever you don't plan to use?

Comment: Along with a 45 degree rotation of your grid coordinates, of course.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not rotating at any point. I've got an array of all the cell locations (center points) and basically know the size of each cell. My images show the shape of the cells but they're not actually there in the game and not used except for the center points.

Comment: Sounds a bit like two separate problems. You want to track the sideways grid and then track the image map where that grid region is clicked, correct?

Comment: Here's a bit of python to calculate position on a sideways grid:`def cspot(x,y,length):
    l=length
    lp=length+1
    vlist = [ (l*(k%2))+(lp*((k+1)%2)) for k in range(1,y+1) ]
    vlist.append(1)
    return x + sum(vlist)
` Sorry, my Javascript isn't what it used to be.

Comment: Wow, that was crappy... Let me add that to my other answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with,

```
function posInGrid(x, y, length) {
xFromColCenter = x % length - length / 2;
yFromRowCenter = y % length - length / 2;
col = (x - xFromColCenter) / length;
row = (y - yFromRowCenter) / length;
if (yFromRowCenter < xFromColCenter) {
    if (yFromRowCenter < (-xFromColCenter))--row;
    else++col;
} else if (yFromRowCenter > xFromColCenter) {
    if (yFromRowCenter < (-xFromColCenter))--col;
    else++row;
}
return "Col:"+col+", Row:"+row+", xFC:"+xFromColCenter+", yFC:"+yFromRowCenter;
}
```

X and Y are the coords in the image, and length is the spacing of the grid.

Right now it returns a string, just for testing.. result should be row and col, and those are the coordinates I chose: your tile 1 has coords (1,0) tile 2 is(3,0), tile 10 is (0,1), tile 11 is (2,1). You could convert my coordinates to your numbered tiles in a line or two.

And a JSFiddle for testing http://jsfiddle.net/NHV3y/

Cheers.

**EDIT:** changed the return statement, had some variables I used for debugging left in.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't able to translate that into JavaScript last night, my brain sort of gave up after a while of poring over the problem. It's an interesting one.

Comment: @Albert No problem, it was fun to play with that. Please remember to accept the answer if you feel it solved your question.

Comment: @jcane86 That's a very interesting method you posted there. I'll take a look at it tomorrow and test if it works in my case (and probably add some minor changes here and there if/when needed). Thanks a lot

Comment: @Dennis Hey, if you are not going to accept an answer you could at least let us know how it went. Did you solve the problem? did you use any of the solutions pointed to in the answers?

Comment: @jcan86 Sorry I went on a vacation right after, so didn't get to follow up on the question. I haven't tested the script yet, but it did seem to work on jsfiddle so I assume it's the right answer (at least to my question, whether it fits my project or not)

Answer (score 0):

A pixel perfect way of hit detection I've used in the past (in OpenGL, but the concept stands here too) is an off screen rendering of the scene where the different objects are identified with different colors.

This approach requires double the memory and double the rendering but the hit detection of arbitrarily complex scenes is done with a simple color lookup.

Since you want to detect a cell in a grid there are probably more efficient solutions but I wanted to mention this one for it's simplicity and flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I should probably have mentioned that these cells are not objects and not generated as such. I DO however use a buffer to detect clicks on normal objects in the game, but not for the cells as they basically don't exist in the game (except for object alignment)

Comment: I don't see how that invalidates this approach. You can have one more buffer for cell hit detection, if the grid is static all the better - you only need to render the buffer once.

Comment: It's not the buffer that's the issue. The issue with your approach is that there are no cells in the game at all except for alignment of other objects which aren't always there. The lines (grid) are basically just lines and there to show you the cells. They are not filled out with any sprite or color. Would I have to use a sprite/texture of a cell shape in the buffer then if that's what you mean?

Comment: I was hoping for a math solution though.

Comment: As I said, there is probably a more efficient solution. But a math solution will only be more memory efficient in this case, it can't beet a simple color lookup. The offscreen buffer (the same resolution as the onscreen buffer) would need to render each cell with a solid unique color and you would need to separately have a mapping between those colors and cell identifiers. When you read the mouse position on the onscreen buffer you then check the color at those coordinates on the offscreen buffer and map it to your cell identifier.

Answer (score -1):

This has been solved before, let me consult my notes...

Here's a couple of good resources:

[From Laserbrain Studios, The basics of isometric programming](http://laserbrainstudios.com/2010/08/the-basics-of-isometric-programming/)

[Useful article in the thread posted here, in Java](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/445320-isometric-tile-coordinates/)

Let me know if this helps, and good luck with your game!

This code calculates the position in the grid given the uneven spacing. Should be pretty fast; almost all operations are done mathematically, using just one loop. I'll ponder the other part of the problem later.

```
def cspot(x,y,length):
    l=length
    lp=length+1
    vlist = [ (l*(k%2))+(lp*((k+1)%2)) for k in range(1,y+1) ]
    vlist.append(1)
    return x + sum(vlist)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but unfortunately these articles (and many others) are based on a diamond shaped map which mine isn't (if you take a look at the pictures) which is what makes my head spin when trying to do these calculations.

Comment: I downvoted by accident, it doesnt let me undownvote. My sincere apologies

Comment: No, no it doesn't.