# How to transform mouse location in isometric tiling map?

Tags: algorithm, math

So I've managed myself to write the first part (algorithm) to calculate each tile's position where should it be placed while drawing this map (see bellow). However I need to be able to convert mouse location to the appropriate cell and I've been almost pulling my hair off because I can't figure out a way how to get the cell from mouse location. My concern is that it involves some pretty high math or something i'm just something easy i'm not capable to notice.
For example if the mouse position is **112;35** how do i calculate/transform it to to get that the cell is **2;3** at that position?
Maybe there is some really good math-thinking programmer here who would help me on this or someone who knows how to do it or can give some information?

[image]

```
var cord:Point = new Point();
cord.x = (x - 1) * 28 + (y - 1) * 28;
cord.y = (y - 1) * 14 + (x - 1) * (- 14);
```

Speaking of the map, each cell (transparent tile *56x28* pixels)  is placed in the center of the previous cell (or at zero position for the cell 1;1), above is the code I use for converting cell-to-position. I tried lot of things and calculations for position-to-cell but each of them failed.

**Edit:**
After reading lot of information *it seems* that using off screen color map (where colors are mapped to tiles) is the fastest and most efficient solution?

Comment: what are you using for drawing?  Many graphic frameworks (like OpenGL) have helper methods to do the mouse-to-world transform for you.

Comment: see Q:[click-detection-in-a-2d-isometric-grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611982/click-detection-in-a-2d-isometric-grid)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(1) x` = 28x -28 + 28y -28  = 28x + 28y -56
(2) y` = -14x +14 +14y -14 = -14x + 14y
```

Transformation table:

```
[x] [28  28 -56 ] = [x`]
[y] [-14 14  0  ]   [y`]
[1] [0    0  1  ]   [1 ]

[28  28 -56 ] ^ -1 
[-14 14  0  ]
[0    0  1  ]
```

Calculate that with a plotter ( I like **[wims](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/wims.cgi)** )

```
[1/56 -1/28  1 ]
[1/56  1/28  1 ]
[0      0    1 ]

x = 1/56*x` - 1/28y` + 1
y = 1/56*x` + 1/28y` + 1
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix .. Basically if you know one side of the transformation, it's easy to get the other side.. So you have V*A=V` .. Multiply A(-1) on both sides and you get V*1=V`*A(-1)

Comment: What I'm transforming? The whole map image to make it rectangle based and then easy calculating the cell?

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the mouse position-to-cell with math without having to rotate the map image?

Comment: @Yochai Timmer Nice solution. Is not it just an Affine Transformation?

Comment: Also would such transformation be pixel accurate? And how efficient it would be to do these transformations on eveeery mouse movement?

Comment: @Richards: If what you gave us is the accurate transformation you had to draw the map, then this should be the reverse transformation and should work on any pixel.

Comment: @Nikiton: Yea basically it's an Affine transformation, but it's better to understand the math than blindly look at the mathematical explanation of an affine transformation:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

Comment: @Yochai, "accurate transformation" you mean the formula for getting the position for drawing the map in my main post?

Comment: @Yochai, also would this transform the whole map image or applies only to transformation of mouse location?

Comment: @Richards: it works on any pair of coordinates (x,y). to transform the whole map you would need to calculate for the whole map. The transformation is to calculate a pixel's position.

Comment: I assume that this the right way for the transformation table, but I will make a new question regarding to how to implement this in Actionscript 3 in Flash. Thanks!

Comment: @Yochai I know this is an old thread but I need the information.  My problem is with the math x` = 28x -28 + 28y -28  = 28x + 28y -48  shouldn't this be x` = 28x -28 + 28y -28  = 28x + 28y -56?  which would change everything?  So would the final  x/y be this x = 1/56*x` - 1/28y` + 1
y = 1/56*x` + 1/28y` + 1  and I'm not sure what x` and y` are is this just 1/56*(28x+28y-56)+1/28(-14x+14y)+1?

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old post, but I want to update this since some people might still look for answers to this issue, just like I was earlier today. However, I figured this out myself. There is also a much better way to render this so you don't get tile overlapping issues.

The code is as simple as this:

```
mouse_grid_x = floor((mouse_y / tile_height) + (mouse_x / tile_width));
mouse_grid_y = floor((-mouse_x / tile_width) + (mouse_y / tile_height));
```

`mouse_x` and `mouse_y` are mouse screen coordinates.

`tile_height` and `tile_width` are actual tile size, not the image itself. As you see on my example picture I've added dirt under my tile, this is just for easier rendering, actual size is 24 x 12. The coordinates are also "floored" to keep the result grid x and y rounded down.

Also notice that I render these tiles from the y=0 and x=tile_with / 2 (red dot). This means my 0,0 actually starts at the top corner of the tile (tilted) and not out in open air. See these tiles as rotated squares, you still want to start from the 0,0 pixel.

Tiles will be rendered beginning with the Y = 0 and X = 0 to map size. After first row is rendered you skip a few pixels down and to the left. This will make the next line of tiles overlap the first one, which is a great way to keep the layers overlapping coorectly. You should render tiles, then whatever in on that tile before moving on to the next.

I'll add a render example too:

```
for (yy = 0; yy < map_height; yy++)
{
     for (xx = 0; xx < map_width; xx++)
     {
          draw tiles here with tile coordinates:
          tile_x = (xx * 12) - (yy * 12) - (tile_width / 2)
          tile_y = (yy * 6) + (xx * 6)

          also draw whatever is on this tile here before moving on
     }
}
```

[image: Isometric Image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I rendered the tiles like above.

the sollution is VERY simple!

**first thing:**

my Tile width and height are both = **32**
this means that in isometric view, 
the width = 32 and height = 16!
Mapheight in this case is 5 (max. Y value)

y_iso & x_iso == 0 when y_mouse=MapHeight/tilewidth/2 and x_mouse = 0

when x_mouse +=1, y_iso -=1

so first of all I calculate the *"per-pixel transformation"*

TileY = ((y_mouse*2)-((MapHeight*tilewidth)/2)+x_mouse)/2;

TileX = x_mouse-TileY;

to find the tile coordinates I just devide both by tilewidth

TileY = TileY/32;
TileX = TileX/32;

DONE!!
never had any problems!

Comment: Thanks for this, been searching for a solution for ages!

Answer (score 1):

I've found algorithm on this site http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/tut18.html. I couldn't get it to work for me properly, but I change it by trial and error to this form and it works for me now.

```
int x = mouse.x + offset.x - tile[0;0].x; //tile[0;0].x is the value of x form witch map was drawn
int y = mouse.y + offset.y;
double _x =((2 * y + x) / 2);
double _y= ((2 * y - x) / 2);
double tileX = Math.round(_x / (tile.height - 1)) - 1;
double tileY = Math.round(_y / (tile.height - 1));
```

This is my map generation

```
for(int x=0;x<max_X;x++)
for(int y=0;y<max_Y;y++)
map.drawImage(image, ((max_X - 1) * tile.width / 2) - ((tile.width - 1) / 2 * (y - x)), ((tile.height - 1) / 2) * (y + x));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to rotate it back to a square projection:

First translate y so that the dimensions are relative to the origin:

```
 x0 = x_mouse;
 y0 = y_mouse-14
```

Then scale by your tile size:

```
 x1 = x/28;   //or maybe 56?
 y1 = y/28
```

Then rotate by the projection angle

```
 a = atan(2/1);   
 x_tile = x1 * cos(a) - y1 * sin(a);
 y_tile = y1 * cos(a) + x1 * sin(a);
```

I may be missing a minus sign, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Rotating back the whole map image yes? To make it rectangle based?

Comment: you wouldn't really have to rotate the whole map.  Just apply the rotation to the mouse location, and you get the equivalent location in coordinates as if the map had been rotated.  However, I think @yochai's answer is a more practical solution.

Comment: Does it applies rotation only to mouse location in @yochai's example too? Or not? Because I don't see how can I skew or rotate mouse location, for example, (112,35).

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't mention it in your original question, in comments I think you said you're programming this in Flash. In which case Flash comes with Matrix transformation functions. The most robust way to convert between coordinate systems (eg. to isometric coordinates) is using Matrix transformations:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html

You would want to rotate and scale the matrix in the inverse of how you rotated and scaled the graphics.