# How to use transformation table in Matrix class?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I, if it's even possible, use this transformation table provided in my question's accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915555/how-to-transform-mouse-location-in-isometric-tiling-map/6915730#6915730) in Actionscript 3 in Flash? I understand it might have something to do with Matrix, but I really have no clue if that transformation provided in the answer is possible to implement there. Is it? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so let's start with your transformation as a [Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html#Matrix%28%29) (which I shifted a bit just to look better--that's what the last two values do).

```
private var gridTransform:Matrix = new Matrix(28, -14, 28, 14, 0, 14);
```

Now if you create a UIComponent, you can use this matrix to draw your grid:

```
var grid:UIComponent = new UIComponent();

grid.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 0);
grid.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x888888);

for (var u:int = 0; u < 20; u++)
{
    for (var v:int = 0; v < 20; v++)
    {
        grid.graphics.moveTo(getX(u,v), getY(u,v));
        grid.graphics.lineTo(getX(u+1,v), getY(u+1,v));
        grid.graphics.lineTo(getX(u+1,v+1), getY(u+1,v+1));
        grid.graphics.lineTo(getX(u,v+1), getY(u,v+1));
    }
}
grid.graphics.endFill();
```

using the helper functions:

```
private function getX(u:Number, v:Number):Number
{
  return gridTransform.transformPoint(new Point(u,v)).x;
}

private function getY(u:Number, v:Number):Number
{
  return gridTransform.transformPoint(new Point(u,v)).y;
}
```

**Note:** *I know that the drawing method is redundant, but I'm also doing it this way so that the fill allows for the area between the grid to register click events.  There are better ways to do it, but it's not the main point.*

Once you've drawn the grid on the UIComponent you can add it to the display list:

```
addChild(grid);
```

(I'm using Flex4, so I use `addElement(grid);`)

And to show how to map mouse events back to (u,v) coordinates, add an event listener to the `grid`:

```
grid.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, grid_clickHandler);
```

where we have:

```
private function grid_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Local coordinates: (" + event.localX + "," + event.localY + ")");
    var inverted:Matrix = gridTransform.clone();
    inverted.invert();
    trace("U-V Coordinates: " + inverted.transformPoint(new Point(event.localX,event.localY)));

}
```

If you only want your U-V coordinates to have whole numbers you can use a `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()` or something like that.